# image protection using php

Tags: php, image

I am blulding a script that will show a small thumbnail from an original photo. In case the user paid for this image we will generate a link for this user to download it at anytime.

the problem is where is the best place to save the original photos? Also, how I can make sure that the user will not be able to access other original photos from the store?

What I was thinking of is to put the original photos in a folder let's call it `orgImages/`. When the user pay the download link will be like this.

`http://www.mysite.com?download.php&token=sha1(UserLoggedInID)&pic=7726`

in `download.php` I will write a smiler code

```
<?php
    $user_logged_in_id = $_SESSION['current_user'];
    $expected_token = sh1($user_logged_in_id);

    if($_GET['token'] == $expected_token && isset($_GET['pic'])){
        // get the picture original link 
        // generate .zip file that contains the image. 
        // let the user download the .zip file. 
    }
?>
```

I don't know if this the correct way to do it. I would feel better if someone's gave the correct way or a hint of how this process can be done.

Comment: "I don't know if this the correct way to do it." --- what do you think?

Comment: best place to save inaccessible content is above web root. Then, like you demonstrate here, deliver it via a script and not directly.

Comment: @zerkms if I knew this before, this question will not be existed. I need some opinions in here.

Comment: @Jason: Now if you change the `pic` parameter you can download whatever you want, can't you?

Comment: This is broadly the approach I'd use, but there's lots of detail missing.

Comment: `I need some opinions in here.` - Stack Overflow is not really the place for a discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would work good if you add some secret key and the picture id, like:

```
$token = sha1('somesecretkey|' . $user_id . '|' . $picture_id);
```

In this case it's a bit more complicated to forge it.

Also it's easy to add an expiration date into this scheme if you ever want it:

```
$token = sha1('somesecretkey|' . $user_id . '|' . $picture_id . '|' . $expire);
```

and pass `expire` timestamp as a parameter. Then in script after you've checked that token is correct - check it's not expired yet.

Also, if you change your secret key - you could invalidate all the links at once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are on the correct way, you just have to make sure that you validate the $_GET["pic"] parameter before delivering anything to the user.

If this is not done right, you can open a giant security flaw on your software and server.